# Braintree one time payment request taking too much time to load

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, braintree

I'm using BTPayPalDriver to call a request of one time payment. But the Sign in alert is taking too much time to load on the display.

```
let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: 
FunctionManager.APPDELEGATE().braintreeClient)
payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self // Optional        

    let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: "0.99")
    request.currencyCode = "USD" // Optional; see BTPayPalRequest.h for more options

    payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) in
    if let tokenizedPayPalAccount = tokenizedPayPalAccount {
            print("Got a nonce: \(tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce)")
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question within the context of StackOverflow?

Comment: @JeremyP, Braintree payment request alert is taking too much time to load when request.

Comment: Excellent, but what is your question? Do you think it's a problem in your code?  If you think it is a problem elsewhere, Stackoverflow is not the right site for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use  `- (void)appContextWillSwitch:(nonnull id)appSwitcher;` delegate callback in order to be notified when the process for showing the PayPal UI will start. You can show a loader until this method is called.

For reference here is a relevant issue in Braintree iOS SDK Github.
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/404